# How to set up a basic test method for a java program using junit?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have a project that is a hardware store consisting of methods that save, search, and edit data. The data is the items stored in a txt database. I have to create a JUNIT test case that tests the methods of the hardware store class. There are three classes in total: hardwarestore, mainapp, and item. But the only one that needs to be tested is hardwarestore. And the only methods that don't need to be tested are the readDatabase() and the writeDatabase().

For my JUNIT classes I have hardwarestoretest that I will implement with test methods for the hardwarestore class. I also have a testrunner class that runs the test methods in hardwarestoretest. The test methods will compose of assertion tests.
[Assertions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwJEO.png)

I am fairly new with JUNIT testing and need just some help getting started. I wrote part of the test classes but they fail when ran. The output I get says that there are no runnable tests even though I tried to implement a test method for addNewItem.

Here is my code for hardwarestore in a hardwarestore package

Item.java

```
package hardwarestore;

/**
 * This class is a very simple representation of a hardware item. There are only getter
 * methods and no setter methods and as a result an item cannot be mutated once
 * initialized. An item object can also call the two override methods
 * <CODE>toString()</CODE> and <CODE>equals()</CODE>
 *
 * @author Junye Wen
 */
public class Item {

    private final String idNumber;
    private final String name;
    private final String category;
    private int quantity;
    private final float price;

    /**
     * This constructor initializes the item object. The constructor provides no
     * user input validation. That should be handled by the class that creates a
     * item object.
     *
     * @param idNumber a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that represents the ID
     *                 random string of length 5 – can contain letters and numbers
     *
     * @param name a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that represents the name.
     *
     * @param category a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that represents the category.
     *                 Door&Window, Cabinet& Furniture, Fasteners, Structural, Other.
     *
     * @param quantity a <b><CODE>int</CODE></b> that represents the quantity
     *
     * @param price an <b><CODE>float</CODE></b> that represents the price
     *
     */
    public Item(String idNumber, String name, String category, int quantity, float price) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the item's tracking number.
     *
     * @return a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that is the ID number of the item.
     */
    public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the item's name.
     *
     * @return a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that is the item's name.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the item's category.
     *
     * @return a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that is the item's category.
     */
    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }


    /**
     * This method returns the item's quantity.
     *
     * @return an <b><CODE>int</CODE></b> that is the item's weight
     */
    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    /**
     * This method set the item's quantity.
     *
     *  @param quantity a <b><CODE>int</CODE></b> that represents the quantity
     */
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity= quantity;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the item's price.
     *
     * @return a <b><CODE>float</CODE></b> that is the item's price
     */
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * This method returns the item's fields as a string representation.
     *
     * @return a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that lists the fields of the item
     * object delineated by a space and in the same order as the constructor
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return idNumber + "~" + name + "~" + category + "~" + quantity + "~"
                + String.format("%.2f", price) + "\n";
    }

    /**
     * This method provides a way to compare two item objects.
     *
     * @param c a <b><CODE>Item</CODE></b> object that is used to compare to
     * <b><CODE>this</CODE></b> item. Two orders are equal if their ID is the
     * same.
     * @return the <CODE>boolean</CODE> value of the comparison.
     */
    public boolean equals(Item c) {
        return c.getIdNumber().equals(this.idNumber);
    }

}
```

HardwareStore.java

```
package hardwarestore;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This class is used to represent a database interface for a list of
 * <CODE>item</CODE>'s. It using a plain-text file "database.txt" to store and
 * write item objects in readable text form. It contains an
 * <CODE>ArrayList</CODE> called <CODE>itemList</CODE> to store the database in
 * a runtime friendly data structure. The <CODE>itemList</CODE> is written to
 * "database.txt" at the end of the <CODE>HardwareStore</CODE> object's life by
 * calling <CODE>writeDatabase()</CODE>. This class also provides methods for
 * adding, removing, and searching for items in the list.
 *
 * @author Junye Wen
 */
public class HardwareStore {

    private ArrayList<Item> itemList;

    private static final String DATA_FILE_NAME = "database.txt";

    /**
     * This constructor creates an empty ArrayList and then calls the 
     * <CODE>readDatabase()</CODE> method to populate items previously stored. 
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public HardwareStore() throws IOException {
        itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        readDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * Method getAllItemsFormatted returns the current list of items in the Arraylist in
     * no particular order.
     * 
     * @return a formatted String representation of all the items in itemList.
     */
    public String getAllItemsFormatted() {
        return getFormattedItemList(itemList);
    }

    /**
     * Private method getFormattedPackageList used as an auxiliary method to return a given ArrayList
     * of items in a formatted manner.
     *
     * @param items the item list to be displayed.
     * @return a formatted String representation of all the items in the list give as a parameter.
     */
    private String getFormattedItemList(ArrayList<Item> items) {

        String text = " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" +
                String.format("| %-10s| %-25s| %-20s| %-10s| %-10s|%n", "ID Number", "Name", "Category", "Quantity", "Price") +
                      " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            text += String.format("| %-10s| %-25s| %-20s| %-10s| %-10s|%n",
                    items.get(i).getIdNumber(),
                    items.get(i).getName(),
                    items.get(i).getCategory(),
                    Integer.toString(items.get(i).getQuantity()),
                    String.format("%.2f", items.get(i).getPrice()));
        }
        text += " ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n";

        return text;
    }


    /**
     * This method is used to add a item to the itemList ArrayList.
     *
     * @param idNumber a <CODE>String</CODE> representing the ID number of item
     * @param name a <CODE>String</CODE> representing the name of item
     * @param category a <CODE>String</CODE> representing the category of item
     * @param quantiy an <CODE>int</CODE> representing the quantiy of item
     * @param price a <CODE>float</CODE> representing the price of item
     */
    public void addNewItem(String idNumber, String name, String category, int quantiy, float price) {
        //If passed all the checks, add the item to the list
        itemList.add(new Item(idNumber, name, category, quantiy, price));
        System.out.println("Item has been added.\n");
    }


    /**
     * Add a certain quantity of the given item index.
     * Preconditions: 1. Item exists.
     * @param itemIndex the index of the item in the itemList
     * @param quantity  the quantity to remove
     */
    public void addQuantity(int itemIndex, int quantity) {
        Item temp = getItem(itemIndex);
        temp.setQuantity(temp.getQuantity() + quantity);
        System.out.println("Quantity updated.\n");
    }


    /**
     * Removes a certain quantity of the given item index. 
     * Preconditions: 1. Item exists. 2. Quantity to remove smaller than current quantity.
     * @param itemIndex the index of the item in the itemList
     * @param quantity  the quantity to remove
     */
    public void removeQuantity(int itemIndex, int quantity) {
        Item temp = getItem(itemIndex);
        temp.setQuantity(temp.getQuantity() - quantity);
        System.out.println("Quantity updated.\n");
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the items that (partially) match the given name.
     * @param name the name to match.
     * @return a string containing a table of the matching items.
     */
    public String getMatchingItemsByName(String name) {
        ArrayList<Item> temp = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (Item tempItem : itemList) {
            if (tempItem.getName().toLowerCase().contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
                temp.add(tempItem);
            }
        }

        if (temp.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return getFormattedItemList(temp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the items with current quantity lower than (or equal) the
     * given threshold.
     * @param quantity the quantity threshold.
     * @return a string containing a table of the matching items.
     */
    public String getMatchingItemsByQuantity(int quantity) {
        ArrayList<Item> temp = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (Item tempItem : itemList) {
            if (tempItem.getQuantity() <= quantity) {
                temp.add(tempItem);
            }
        }

        if (temp.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return getFormattedItemList(temp);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method can be used to find a item in the Arraylist of items.
     *
     * @param idNumber a <CODE>String</CODE> that represents the ID number of
     * the item that to be searched for.
     * @return the <CODE>int</CODE> index of the items in the Arraylist of
     * items, or -1 if the search failed.
     */
    public int findItem(String idNumber) {

        int index = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
            String temp = itemList.get(i).getIdNumber();

            if (idNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(temp)) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }

        }

        return index;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to retrieve the Item object from the
     * <CODE>itemList</CODE> at a given index.
     *
     * @param i the index of the desired <CODE>Item</CODE> object.
     * @return the <CODE>Item</CODE> object at the index or null if the index is
     * invalid.
     */
    public Item getItem(int i) {
        if (i < itemList.size() && i >= 0) {
            return itemList.get(i);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Index.\n");
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method opens the database file and overwrites it with a
     * text representation of all the items in the <CODE>itemList</CODE>. This
     * should be the last method to be called before exiting the program.
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void writeDatabase() throws IOException {
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(DATA_FILE_NAME);

        for (Item c : itemList) {
            pw.print(c.toString());
        }

        pw.close();
    }

    /**
     * The method opens the database file and initializes the <CODE>itemList</CODE> 
     * with its contents. If no such file exists, then one is created. 
     * The contents of the file are "loaded" into the itemList ArrayList in no 
     * particular order. The file is then closed during the duration of the 
     * program until <CODE>writeDatabase()</CODE> is called.
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void readDatabase() throws IOException {

        File dataFile = new File(DATA_FILE_NAME);

        // If data file does not exist, create it.
        if (!dataFile.exists()) {
            System.out.println("database.txt does not exist, creating one now . . .");
            //if the file doesn't exists, create it
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(DATA_FILE_NAME);
            //close newly created file so we can reopen it
            pw.close();

            return; // No need to try to read anything from an empty file, so return.
        }
        Scanner itemScanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(dataFile));

        //Initialize the Array List with items from database.txt
        while (itemScanner.hasNextLine()) {

            // split values using the space character as separator
            String[] temp = itemScanner.nextLine().split("~");

            itemList.add(new Item(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2],
                    Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), Float.parseFloat(temp[4])));
        }

        //item list is now in the ArrayList completely so we can close the file
        itemScanner.close();
    }

}
```

MainApp.java

```
package hardwarestore;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This is the main class of the Hardware Store database manager. It provides a
 * console for a user to use the 5 main commands.
 *
 * @author Junye Wen
 */
public class MainApp {

    // This object will allow us to interact with the methods of the class HardwareStore
    private final HardwareStore hardwareStore;
    private static final Scanner CONSOLE_INPUT = new Scanner(System.in); // Used to read from System's standard input

    /**
     * Default constructor. Initializes a new object of type HardwareStore
     *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public MainApp() throws IOException {
        hardwareStore = new HardwareStore();
    }

    /**
     * Shows all items in the inventory.
     */
    public void showAllItems() {
        System.out.print(hardwareStore.getAllItemsFormatted());
    }

    /**
     * This method will add items quantity with given number. If the item does
     * not exist, it will call another method to add it.
     *
     */
    public void addItemQuantity() {

        System.out.println("Please input the ID of item");
        String idNumber = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextLine();

        if (!idNumber.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]{5}")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid ID Number: not proper format. "
                    + "ID Number must be 5 alphanumeric characters.\n");
            return;
        }

        int itemIndex = hardwareStore.findItem(idNumber);
        if (itemIndex != -1) { // If item exists in the database

            System.out.println("Item found in database. Please enter quantity to add.");
            int quantity = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextInt();
            if (quantity <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid quantity. "
                        + "The addition amount must be larger than 0.\n");
                return;
            }
            hardwareStore.addQuantity(itemIndex, quantity);
        } else {
            //If it reaches here, the item does not exist. We need to add new one.
            System.out.println("Item with given number does not exist.\n");

            // Enter name
            System.out.println("\nPlease type the name of item.");
            String name = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextLine();

            // Entery category
            String category = null;
            System.out.println("\nPlease select the category of item.");
            System.out.println("1: Door&Window\n2: Cabinet&Furniture\n3: Fasteners\n4: Structural\n5: Other");
            int selection = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextInt();
            switch (selection) {
                case 1:
                    category = "Door&Window";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    category = "Cabinet&Furniture";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    category = "Fasteners";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    category = "Structural";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    category = "Other";
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid category number.");
                    return;
            }

            // Entery quantity
            System.out.println("\nPlease type the quantity of the item.");
            int quantity = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextInt();
            if (quantity < 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid price. "
                        + "The quantity cannot be smaller than 0.");
                return;
            }

            // Enter price
            System.out.println("\nPlease type the price of the item.");
            float price = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextFloat();
            if (price < 0) {
                System.out.println("Invalid price. "
                        + "The price cannot be smaller than 0.");
                return;
            }

            hardwareStore.addNewItem(idNumber, name, category, quantity, price);
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method will remove the given quantity of an item with given number.
     * If the item does not exist, it will show an appropriate message.
     */
    public void removeItemQuantity() {

        System.out.println("Please input the ID of item");
        String idNumber = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextLine();
        if (!idNumber.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]{5}")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid ID Number: not proper format. "
                    + "ID Number must be at least 5 alphanumeric characters.");
            return;
        }

        int itemIndex = hardwareStore.findItem(idNumber);
        int currentQuantity;
        if (itemIndex == -1) {
            System.out.println("Item does not exist.\n");
            return;
        } else {
            currentQuantity = hardwareStore.getItem(itemIndex).getQuantity();
            System.out.println("Current quantity: " + currentQuantity + "\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Please input the quantity to remove.");
        int quantity = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextInt();
        if (quantity > currentQuantity) {
            System.out.println("Invalid quantity. "
                    + "The removal amount must be smaller than current quantity.\n");
        } else {
            hardwareStore.removeQuantity(itemIndex, quantity);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method can search item by a given name (part of name.
     * Case-insensitive.) Will display all items with the given name.
     */
    public void searchItemByName() {

        System.out.println("Please input the name of item.\n");
        String name = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextLine();

        String output = hardwareStore.getMatchingItemsByName(name);
        if (output == null) {
            System.out.println("Item not found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method can search item below a certain quantity. Will display all
     * items fits such condition.
     */
    public void searchItemByQuantity() {

        System.out.println("Please enter the quantity:\n");
        int quantity = CONSOLE_INPUT.nextInt();

        if (quantity < 0) {
            System.out.println("Quantity should be at least 0.\n");
        }

        String output = hardwareStore.getMatchingItemsByQuantity(quantity);
        if (output == null) {
            System.out.println("No items found below given quantity.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
    }

    public void saveDatabase() throws IOException {
        hardwareStore.writeDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * This method will begin the user interface console. Main uses a loop to
     * continue executing commands until the user types '6'.
     *
     * @param args this program expects no command line arguments
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        MainApp app = new MainApp();

        String welcomeMessage = "\nWelcome to the Hardware Store database. Choose one of the following functions:\n\n"
                + "\t1. Show all existing items in stock and their quantities.\n"
                + "\t2. Add a new quantity of a specific item to the stock.\n"
                + "\t3. Remove a certain quantity of a specific item type.\n"
                + "\t4. Search for an item (given its name or part of its name).\n"
                + "\t5. Show a list of all items below a certain quantity.\n"
                + "\t6. Exit program.\n";

        System.out.println(welcomeMessage);

        int selection = CONSOLE_INPUT.next().charAt(0);
        CONSOLE_INPUT.nextLine();

        while (selection != '6') {

            switch (selection) {
                case '1':
                    app.showAllItems();
                    break;
                case '2':
                    app.addItemQuantity();
                    break;
                case '3':
                    app.removeItemQuantity();
                    break;
                case '4':
                    app.searchItemByName();
                    break;
                case '5':
                    app.searchItemByQuantity();
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    System.out.println(welcomeMessage);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("That is not a recognized command. Please enter another command or 'h' to list the commands.");
                    break;

            }

            System.out.println("Please enter another command or 'h' to list the commands.\n");
            selection = CONSOLE_INPUT.next().charAt(0);

            CONSOLE_INPUT.nextLine();
        }

        CONSOLE_INPUT.close();


        System.out.print("Saving database...");
        app.saveDatabase();

        System.out.println("Done!");

    }
}
```

Here are my test classes in a test package

HardwareStoreTest.java

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import hardwarestore.*;

public class HardwareStoreTest {

    public static HardwareStore hardwarestore = null;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void createEnvironment() throws IOException {
        hardwarestore = new HardwareStore();
    }

    @AfterClass 
    public static void clearEnvironment() {
        hardwarestore = null;
        System.out.println("Environment cleared");
    }

    @Test
    public static void testAddItem() {
        hardwarestore.addNewItem("123543","sink","other",23,24.95f);
        assertNotNull("Test Failed message", hardwarestore.getItem(0));
    }

}
```

TestRunner.java

```
package test;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

class TestRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(HardwareStoreTest.class);
    if(result.getFailures().size()==0) {
        System.out.println("All tests successfull!");
    }else {
        System.out.println("No. of failed test cases = "+ result.getFailures().size());
        for(Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Maybe HardwareStoreTest.java is not compiled after adding @Test annotation to test method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your import at the top and the Test shouldn't be static.

```
import org.junit.Test

@Test
public void addNewItem(){
    hardwarestore.addNewItem("123RT", "sink", "kitchen", 34, 4.51f);
    assertNotNull("Test Failed Message", hardwarestore.getItem(0));

}
```